# Image file size increases when uploading to the server

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am using the `Intervention\Image` package for laravel

Here are my image upload functions, the first is a regular upload, the second is a resize

```
public function saveImage(Request $request, $requestField, $path)
{
    if ($request->hasFile($requestField)) {

        $image_path = public_path($this->{$requestField});

        if (File::exists($image_path)) {
            File::delete($image_path);
        }

        $file = $request->file($requestField);
        $uploadname = $this->getUploadName($file);
        $pathFull = public_path($path);

        if (!File::exists($pathFull)) {
            File::makeDirectory($pathFull, 0775, true);
        }

        $replaced = str_replace('_', '-', $requestField);
        Image::make($file)->save($pathFull.$replaced .'-'. $uploadname);
        $this->{$requestField} = $path.$replaced .'-'. $uploadname;

        return $file;
    }

    return false;
}

public function copyImage($file, $requestField, $path, $width, $heigth)
{
    $image_path = public_path($this->{$requestField});

    if (File::exists($image_path)) {
        File::delete($image_path);
    }

    $uploadname = $this->getUploadName($file);
    $pathFull = public_path($path);

    if (!File::exists($pathFull)) {
        File::makeDirectory($pathFull, 0775, true);
    }

    $replaced = str_replace('_', '-', $requestField);
    Image::make($file)->fit($width, $heigth, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->upsize();
    })->save($pathFull.$replaced .'-'. $uploadname);

    return $path.$replaced .'-'. $uploadname;
}
```

But it turns out that, let's say I upload an image with a file size of 200KB, and on the server it becomes 400KB

Could it be related to the use of the `Intervention\Image` package or could it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode), you can use the `encode()` method to vary compression levels on the saved image. The number (0-100) indicates "quality" where a higher number will take up more bytes. So something like this should help reduce file size; you'll need to experiment to find out what level works best for your requirements.

```php
Image::make($file)
    ->fit($width, $heigth, fn ($constraint) => $constraint->upsize())
    ->encode('jpg', 75)
    ->save($pathFull . $replaced . '-' . $uploadname);
```